# Caching the results of a query and making smaller queries against it

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm working with a database where I'll have to make a query for a certain ID as requests come in. My issue is that the DBAs have stipulated that I should simply take a batch copy of the entirety of the table for a given day and cache that.

This would mean I have to do a periodic `select *`, keep that in memory and any time a request comes in for an individual userId, point it to the cached version. However if the cache has expired I need to then do the large query again.

This all sounds achievable in theory but I don't know what API I should be using.

Comment: What kind of DBAs do you have? That's exactly the job of the Database

Comment: I did think it was a bit of an odd request.